# Consecutive PreparedStatement good practice

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm executing a few `SELECT`s in a row and I'm wondering how I should handle the `PreparedStatement`s.

Example code:

```
//Connection conn is already declared
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
ResultSet rset = null;
try {
  String sql = "SELECT ...";
  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  pstmt.setString(1, someVar);

  rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
  // Use ResultSet

  // A different query
  sql = "SELECT ...";
  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
  pstmt.setString(1, someVar);

  rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
  // Use ResultSet
} catch (SQLException e) {
  // Handle
} finally {
  if (rset != null)
    rset.close();
  if (pstmt != null)
    pstmt.close();
  if (conn != null)
    conn.close();
}
```

Now the question is, would it be better to close the `PreparedStatement`s after each usage/use different statements or would it make absolutely no difference?

I've found some information about reusing a `PreparedStatement` that always has the same query but I'm not sure about using different queries.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in this example the difference between using the same one and using two would be negligible. If you were however using them both multiple times in a loop then having two would be the way to go, since you wouldn't have to recompile the queries each time on the database.

Comment: If you have different queries you'd need to use several statements or build switches into the statements (if possible) - I'd go for the more maintainable and readable option and use multiple statements.

Comment: This is a pretty odd construct. Are the results to be related/combinied in a single final result? Yes? Are you familiar with SQL `JOIN` clause? I'd invest time in learning it so that you can end up with a single SQL query. Or if it are two completely standalone queries, I'd execute it in separate method bodies.

Comment: @BalusC Yeah I know `JOIN`s. They are 2 unrelated `SELECT`s used to generate a report.

Comment: Go ahead learning the `JOIN` then.

Comment: Normal practice is to write and construct the SQL query that way so that it returns **exactly** the result you need instead of cobbling different results from the same DB together in Java side. SQL is much more powerful than you'd think. It has lot of useful functions and clauses.

Comment: @BalusC I know SQL much more than I know Java actually. My queries are on two different, unrelated tables and are used to generate data about two different things that will go in the same report. Assume that my first query selects the number of rainy days in the month and that the second one counts the number of employees in the company.

Comment: I'd execute that in separate method bodies and postprocess the returned results later. This way each is reuseable at its own.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not using the same `PreparedStatement`, the factory method `Connection.prepareStatement` is returning you a new instance each time you call it.  `PreparedStatement.executeQuery` is doing the same with `ResultSet`.  You are just using the same variables.

This means you're leaking resources - the first `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` - every time this method is called, which are never being closed.

My recommendation would be to use Spring's `JdbcTemplate` which will handle these database resources correctly for you and you break your code into two methods.

Comment: In other words, you need to have separate local variables for multiple statements and resultsets and close them *all* in `finally`.

Comment: This top answer here says you can reuse `ResultSet` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903115/reusing-resultset

Comment: @ethamjyx neither example reuses the `ResultSet`, they reuse the variable that references the `ResultSet`.  In the answer you reference, there's no resource leak because the `Statement` is reused (which as stated implicitly closes the `ResultSet` as mentioned); in the above code this isn't the case and there is a resource leak.  At the end of the day, I think both code samples stink - reusing a variable like this is, imho, plain bad.  As for the closing of resources, this should be explicit making it clear to anyone reading the code what's going on.