# Reusing ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I need to run several queries in a row

```
Statement st = cnx.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery( "SELECT [good stuff]");
// do something smart with rs
rs = st.execute( "SELECT [better stuff]");
// do something smarter with rs
rs = st.execute( "SELECT [best stuff]");
// you got it
try{ rs.close();} catch( SQLException ignore){};
try{ st.close();} catch( SQLException ignore){};
```

Is this a problem that the first two ResultSet are not properly closed or is it implicitely done during garbage collection?

Comment: Can you do your "smart" and "smarter" stuff in sql to do this in a single query?  It might be one consideration...

Comment: that was the whole point of the question

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As soon as you execute the 2nd query, the previous `ResultSet` is automatically closed. And as far as `Garbage Collection` is concerned, you don't have to worry about that. You can just have a `stmt.close()` at the end that's all. It will automatically close all the related `ResultSet` objects.

Take a look at : - [`ResultSet#close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close%28%29) documentation, which says that: -

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed by the Statement object
>   that generated it when that Statement object is closed, re-executed,
>   or is used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple
>   results.

If you want to test, whether your resultset gets closed or not, you can use a while loop to iterate over the `result set` and inside the while loop, create another query and assign it to same result set. You will see that an Exception will be thrown..

```
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sometable");

while (res.next()) {
    res.getString(1);

    // Closes the previous `ResultSet`
    res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM othertable");
}
```

So, in the above code, on the 2nd iteration, you will get an `Exception: - Cannot perform operation after ResultSet is closed`

Comment: Thought I would mention that I found this in [ResultSet.close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()) documentation: A ResultSet object is automatically closed by the Statement object that generated it when that Statement object is [...] re-executed

Comment: @MiserableVariable. Exactly. That's what I wrote there.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Thanks for mentioning that. :)

Comment: The answer did not reference `ResultSet.close` when I saw it earlier. I decided to put it in comment since my first stop, `executeQuery` does not document that the previous set is closed.

Comment: Can you please explain why the second iteration will throw exception instead of calling `getString` on the new `ResultSet`, which should be open at that point?

Comment: @MiserableVariable Yeah that's true. Some source is always beneficial.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Since the `ResultSet` gets closed, you cannot do an `res.next()` on it. That's why it will throw an Exception.

Comment: But the `next` is being done on the `ResultSet` created by the *second* `executeQuery`, i.e. `stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM othertable")`, it would throw the exception if you did not assign it again to `res`.

Comment: @MiserableVariable.. No. that is not happening. In `while(res.next())`, res pointed to a different resultset, and then the res is changed in loop. So, it will no longer point to that result set. So, basically the object is lost, on which `while` was operating on.

Comment: @RohitJain: No, that's not how it works. In `while (res.next())`, `next` is called on whatever `ResultSet` that `res` *currently* refers to.

Comment: I was using the FindBugs Eclipse plugin, and it treats this situation as a possible IO leak. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your problem, but if you have some problems to run this code, you can try to close connection and open other to make the second query. Some database products, like SQLite, only admit one open connection. If you have any problem with database access, you should try that.

Comment: I guess It's only psychological. I just want to make sure I am not leaking ResultSets