# how to correctly remove the list of records from the database?

Tags: java, jdbc

I do a simple web-app where user can select checkboxes of items to remove them from database(like mail manager).
So, is there a correct way to do this?

I think to do like this:(in DAO class)

```
void delete(List<Long> ids){
    .....
    statement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM table WHERE id=?");
    for (Long id: ids){
         statement.setInt(1, id);
         statement.executeUpdate();
    }
    ......
```

or this:(in servlet action class)

```
DAO dao = new DAO();
for (Long id: ids){
    dao.delete(id); // in DAO simple method void delete(long id);
    }
```

are not good. Сan you tell or explain how to do it right?
UPDATE: ok, can someone tell me how to delete records not one by one?

Comment: do you get errors? or the items do not actually delete from the database?  what is the issue?

Comment: @Randy, I have no errors, but the code is written so that in case of SQLException may cause serious problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends greatly on whether they're supposed to be deleted in a single transaction or not. Imagine that you need to delete 5 records upon a request and the deletion of 3rd record fails with an exception. What exactly should happen with the first two records and the last two records? That's a business requirement which you've to figure out yourself first.

At least, the DAO/service method which you're calling in the servlet should not care about this. It should be able to take a `Set` of IDs like so (no, not a `List` since it can contain duplicates):

```
Set<Long> ids = collectItSomehow();
someService.delete(ids);
```

Then, in the real JDBC implementation, you could use [`PreparedStatement#addBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) to create a batch of statements and [`PreparedStatement#executeBatch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) to execute it. You can find some concrete examples in this answer: [Reusing a PreparedStatement multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467125/reusing-a-preparedstatement-multiple-times/2467152#2467152).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Long id: ids){
        populateArray;
    }
```

Create array (tempArray) from above loop and pass it here.

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM table WHERE id in("+ tempArray+")");
```

Note: This may cause sql injection if input is not properly validated.

Answer (score -1):

You want to delete the records one by one or selecting more than one record at once?

Comment: I do not know what to say.) I want to delete all selected records, and now I ask exactly how this is best done. I think to delete the records one by one (as in my code) is not good.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer.