# Insert multiple rows into two tables in a single query using JDBC in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have two tables student(id, name, city), teacher(id, name, salary).
And there are several rows which are needed to insert Mysql DB.

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES ('12', 'Tom', 'New York');
INSERT INTO student VALUES ('13', 'Jack', 'New York');
INSERT INTO teacher VALUES ('01', 'Joy', '42000');
INSERT INTO teacher VALUES ('02', 'Ryan', '39000');
```

The connector is JDBC in JAVA, could I write a single query to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `PreparedStatement` and batch insert:

```
List<Student> students = ...
Connection con = ...
String insertSql = "INSERT INTO student VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(insertSql);
for (Student student : students) {
    pstmt.setString(1, student.getId()); //not sure if String or int or long
    pstmt.setString(2, student.getName());
    pstmt.setString(3, student.getCity());
    pstmt.addBatch();
}
pstmt.executeBatch();
//close resources...
```

Similar for your `Teacher`s.

More info:

- [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- [Difference between Statement and PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3271249/1065197)
- [Reusing a PreparedStatement multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2467125/1065197)

Comment: I've still got a lot to learn. I was only suggesting that you can insert multiple rows in one query and still use placeholders.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, Thanks for your comment. Just quick question, what's "placeholders"?

Comment: @Eric A placeholder is the `?` in the sql String. You use them with the `PreparedStatement` to set the values you actually want to use. They are helpful in, among other things, eliminating SQL injection.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis oh,That's good to know! Thank you for sharing knowledge, I think I know how to learn this part.

Comment: @Eric I've updated the answer with link providing useful info

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thank you so much, I am sure it will help not only me but also others don't know about this part.

Comment: @Eric you're welcome. And yes, that's what Q/A mean: help future readers to improve their programming and design skills.