# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-24335: cannot support more than 1000 columns

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I have a java program which inserts a list of store numbers with a unique ID called `pilotID` into an Oracle database with the following syntax:

```
pilotDAO.insertPilotStores(pilotID, storeList);
```

`storeList` is a `List<String>` storing store numbers, and `pilotID` is some integer like 101.

However, when the `storelist` is more than 999 stores, I am getting a DB exception in Oracle:

```
Caused by:
    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-24335: cannot support more than 1000 columns
```

The insert query which in use is

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO eportal.pilot_store (pilot_id, store_nbr, last_updt_dt_tme) VALUES (96, 100, SYSDATE)
  INTO eportal.pilot_store (pilot_id, store_nbr, last_updt_dt_tme) VALUES (96, 101, SYSDATE)
  INTO eportal.pilot_store (pilot_id, store_nbr, last_updt_dt_tme) VALUES (96, 102, SYSDATE)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

I am really stuck here. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance
pooja

Comment: It seems to be a built-in limitation to Oracle's DB software. Maybe try flipping it so that you store to rows instead of columns? I don't really do SQL, so I don't know how you would do that, but it might be a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the INSERT ALL. This feature is designed for multiple table inserts (MTI), it is not designed to insert multiple rows in one table. You can re-write your query to use single insert statements. Or you can write it like this:

```
INSERT INTO eportal.pilot_store (pilot_id, store_nbr, last_updt_dt_tme)
select 96, 100, SYSDATE from dual UNION ALL
select 96, 101, SYSDATE from dual UNION ALL
select 96, 102, SYSDATE from dual UNION ALL
....;
```

Comment: how can i re-write my query for more than 1000 rows.

Comment: @PoojaGupta You can use StringBuilder to re-write your query, see my answer for more details

Comment: @PoojaGupta sol4me has a good solution for writing out all the sql.

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting the maximum number of columns in the database.
you will most likely need to change this into a prepared statement and call it multiple times instead. each "into ...." is considered one column by oracle I would venture so if you have

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO eportal.pilot_store (....)
  999 more rows
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

then yes indeed it will not work.

instead try this ([adapted from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2467152/1197030))

```
public void insertStores(int pilotId, List<Store> stores) throws SQLException { 
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO eportal.pilot_store (pilot_id, store_nbr, last_updt_dt_time) values (?, ?, SYSDATE)");

        // ofcourse adapt to use your own list of store id's etc.
        for (Store store : stores) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, pilotId);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, store.getNumber());
            preparedStatement.addBatch();
        }
        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        connection.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        close(preparedStatement);
        close(connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: I havent use preparedstatement batch statements before.So, if I have to insert more than 999 rows how does addbatch and executebatch will work. Please explain.

Comment: Probably one of the other answers suits better then. The above code should cover everything. otherwise you'll have to look up the relevant documentation

Comment: I use this technique to cram in 100,000 rows at a shot and get performance values of ~ 90,000 rows per second, then again I have some very fast disks and only 1 index.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed INSERT ALL doesn't performs well for big number of rows You can use `UNION ALL` instead

```
INSERT INTO
  eportal.pilot_store (pilot_id, store_nbr, last_updt_dt_tme) 
select 96, 100, SYSDATE from dual
union all
  select 96, 101, SYSDATE from dual
union all 
   select 96, 102, SYSDATE from dual
```

You can re-write you query using StringBuilder like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO eportal.pilot_store (pilot_id, store_nbr, last_updt_dt_tme) ");
String unionAll = " union all ";
for(int i = 100; i < 103; i++) {

    sb.append("select 96,").append(i).append(", SYSDATE from dual").append(unionAll);
}
sb.delete(sb.length() - unionAll.length(), sb.length());
sb.append(";");
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use bulk insert instead of insert all

In Java it will be something like this
[Oracle JDBC batching](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraperf.htm#CHDCCEHD)

Advantages - simple insert query, fine performance.

Using literals in query is not the right choice for Oracle (especially for queries that are run frequently) because oracle will parse query each time,
and will make a mess in shared pool.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me this way:

```
INSERT INTO eportal.pilot_store (pilot_id, store_nbr, last_updt_dt_tme)
        SELECT 96, 100, SYSDATE FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 96, 101, SYSDATE FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 96, 102, SYSDATE FROM dual;
```

Note that the last line should not have the "UNION ALL" sentence.