# Cannot update multiple times using for loop

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a form that borrows stocks from branchA to branchB. The user can input multiple products and I do this by having a text area split it with (","), and place in it an array. After submitting my form, I insert it in a table and then update the stocks from another table. Here is my code (which I actually placed in a JSP file instead of a normal Java class):

```
   try {

      for (int iCtr=0; iCtr<idsplit.length; iCtr++) {

          sInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO PULLOUT_REPORTS (control_number, dateofpullout, item_des, item_size, item_qty, pullout_from, pullout_to) values ('"+cn+"','"+po+"','"+idsplit[iCtr]+"','"+issplit[iCtr]+"','"+qtsplit[iCtr]+"','"+fr+"','"+to+"')";
          pInsertPullout = conn.prepareStatement(sInsertQuery);
          pInsertPullout.executeUpdate();

            if (fr.equals("Antipolo") && to.equals("Binangonan")) {
                      sUpdateRecord = "UPDATE maintable SET antip_qty = antip_qty - ? WHERE item_code = ? AND item_size = ?";
                      pUpdateFrom = conn.prepareStatement(sUpdateRecord);
                      pUpdateFrom.setString(1,qtsplit[iCtr]);
                      pUpdateFrom.setString(2,idsplit[iCtr]);
                      pUpdateFrom.setString(3,issplit[iCtr]);
                      pUpdateFrom.addBatch();

                      pUpdateFrom.executeBatch();

                      sUpdateRecord1 = "UPDATE maintable SET binang_qty = binang_qty + ? WHERE item_code = ? AND item_size = ?";
                      pUpdateTo = conn.prepareStatement(sUpdateRecord1);
                      pUpdateTo.setString(1,qtsplit[iCtr]);
                      pUpdateTo.setString(2,idsplit[iCtr]);
                      pUpdateTo.setString(3,issplit[iCtr]);
                      pUpdateTo.addBatch();

                      pUpdateTo.executeBatch();
                  } }
  }

  catch (Exception e) {
     response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
   }
```

The first query successfully inserts multiple rows in the table but my second query only updates the first index from the array. I don't know what I could be doing wrong since they're both inside the same loop.

Any help please?

**UPDATE: I did this .addBatch and .executeBatch and it work a while, now it doesn't work again. It only updates the first index.**

Comment: On the "best practices" side,  doing this in a JSP is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Santosh Is there any way I could make it work at least?

Comment: Can you print the result of  pUpdateFrom.executeUpdate call? It should the number of impacted line by the update

Comment: Could you please paste the code in its entirety?  This appears to be a partial code snippet.

Comment: @user3211403 Which exception do you get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467125/reusing-a-preparedstatement-multiple-times

Comment: I don't get any exceptions. It just only updates once.

Comment: I'll post the code. @AfsunKhammadli

Comment: I think your `executeBatch()` method must be outside of `for` loop.

Comment: i'll try this out thanks. @AfsunKhammadli I am really really getting frustrated now

Comment: It sometimes happen in programming ))

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli It does not work. It doesn't perform the update when I put the .executeBatch() outside of for loop.

Comment: All this is bad : your first statement is asking for SQL injection, you do batch insert of update for one single value, you have no error logging, and you say this is inside a JSP. But besides of that, if input values are correct, it could work. Do it *by hand* splitting it down : 1/ just output the values for idsplit, qtsplit and issplit  2/ use this values manually in mysql console 3/ use this values in a small java program with hardcoded input and heavy traces. The third step would be a nice MVCE to post here.

Comment: You should prepare statement outside the for loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this snippet (i might ve messed up with types of your variables, because I guessed them.

```
    try {
     sInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO PULLOUT_REPORTS " +
                    "(control_number, dateofpullout, item_des, item_size, item_qty, pullout_from, pullout_to)" +
                    " values " +
                    "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
      pInsertPullout = conn.prepareStatement(sInsertQuery);
      sUpdateRecord = "UPDATE maintable SET antip_qty = antip_qty - ? WHERE item_code = ? AND item_size = ?";
      pUpdateFrom = conn.prepareStatement(sUpdateRecord);
      sUpdateRecord1 = "UPDATE maintable SET binang_qty = binang_qty + ? WHERE item_code = ? AND item_size = ?";
      pUpdateTo = conn.prepareStatement(sUpdateRecord1);

      for (int iCtr=0; iCtr<idsplit.length; iCtr++) {
          pInsertPullout.setLong(1, cn);
          pInsertPullout.setLong(2, po);
          pInsertPullout.setString(3, idsplit[iCtr]);
          pInsertPullout.setString(4, issplit[iCtr]);
          pInsertPullout.setString(5, qtsplit[iCtr]);
          pInsertPullout.setString(6, fr);
          pInsertPullout.setString(7, to);

          pInsertPullout.executeUpdate();
          pInsertPullout.clearParameters();

            if (fr.equals("Antipolo") && to.equals("Binangonan")) {
                      pUpdateFrom.setString(1,qtsplit[iCtr]);
                      pUpdateFrom.setString(2,idsplit[iCtr]);
                      pUpdateFrom.setString(3,issplit[iCtr]);
                      pUpdateFrom.addBatch();


                      pUpdateTo.setString(1,qtsplit[iCtr]);
                      pUpdateTo.setString(2,idsplit[iCtr]);
                      pUpdateTo.setString(3,issplit[iCtr]);
                      pUpdateTo.addBatch();

                  } 
      }
      pUpdateFrom.executeBatch();
      pUpdateTo.executeBatch();
  }

  catch (Exception e) {
     response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
  }
```

and don't forget to cleanup resources afterwards. Close statements and connection in finally{} clause.