# Modified: How to update multiple rows in java jdbc on duplicate value

Tags: java, arrays, jdbc, checkboxlist, on-duplicate-key

I have a .jsp page that has a multi checkbox.  I'm able to insert the multiple checkbox values but when use an update, it adds the current checkbox rows plus the additional checkbox value rows.  If I check one more box it should add 1 more row and so on.

Here is my code that works for update:
**CollDAO.java**:

```
//Insert checkbox records
public void addColl(String qId, String[] arrayColId) {
  try {
    PreparedStatement ps = con.preparedStatement("insert into colTable(qId, colId) values(?,?)");

   for(int i = 0; i < arrayColId.length; i++) {
     ps.setString(1, qId);
     ps.setString(2, arrayColId[i]);
     ps.executeUpdate();
   }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

***If I select 2 checkboxes this is what it looks like.***

**rowid** | **qID** | **cID** --   ***CORRECT***

:101:   | :121: | :9:

:100:   | :121: | :13:

```
//Update checkbox records
public void updateColl(String qId, String[] arrayColId) {
  try {
    String sql = "update colTable set colId=?, where qId=?";
   PreparedStatement ps = con.preparedStatement(sql);

   for(int i = 0; i < colId; i++) {
     ps.setString(1, colId[i]);
     ps.setString(2, qId);
     ps.executeUpdate();
   }

  } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

***If I select 3 checkboxes this is what get updated.***

**rowid** | **qID** | **cID** -- ***WRONG OUTPUT***

:105:   | :121: | :2:

:104:   | :121: | :9:

:103:   | :121: | :13:

:101:   | :121: | :9:

:100:   | :121: | :13:

***This is what it suppose to look like.***

**rowid** | **qID** | **cID** -- ***CORRECT OUTPUT***

:103:   | :121: | :2:

:101:   | :121: | :9:

:100:   | :121: | :13:

I've been working on this for a week, can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: You need to check the values in arrayColID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you should to use Batch instead :

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.preparedStatement("your query");

for(int i = 0; i < arrayColId.length; i++) {
     ps.setString(1, qId);
     ps.setString(2, arrayColId[i]);
     ps.addBatch();    
}

ps.executeBatch();
```

You can learn more here [Reusing a PreparedStatement multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467125/reusing-a-preparedstatement-multiple-times) and [Statament batching](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/)

**Edit**

For your update you can use :

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);

int arrayVals = Math.min(arrayColId.length, arrayQId.length);
for (int i = 0; i < arrayVals; i++) {
    ps.setString(1, arrayColId[i]);
    ps.setString(2, arrayQId[i]);
    ps.addBatch(); //add a batch
}

ps.executeBatch();//execute your batch

connection.commit();//when you finish you should to commit your transaction
```

Comment: @Gee you can use batch with Insert or update or any operation

Comment: yes @Gee, with both of them, did you know how to complete your code, or i should to edit my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136788/discussion-between-ycf-l-and-gee).

Comment: @Gee did you set your action between `connection.setAutoCommit(false);` and `connection.commit();`