# Reusing Postgres prepared statement

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I was looking at this question [Reusing a PreparedStatement multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467125/reusing-a-preparedstatement-multiple-times)

Let's say I have two versions of code. The first closes the `PreparedStatement` after each use, inside the `for` loop.

```
connection.autoCommit(false)    
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setObject(1, someValue);
        preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        preparedStatement.close();    //  Close after each use.
    }
    connection.commit();
    connection.close();
```

In this second example, the `PreparedStatement` remains open for repeated use, to be closed later after the `for` loop.

```
connection.autoCommit(false)
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    preparedStatement.clearParameters();
    preparedStatement.setObject(1, someValue);
    preparedStatement.executeQuery();
}
preparedStatement.close();           //  Close after repeated uses.
connection.commit();
connection.close();
```

As you can see I do create and close PS in loop or reuse the same PS. I do use postgres and according to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html)

> Prepared statements only last for the duration of the current database session. When the session ends, the prepared statement is forgotten

As I understand if I use postgres then two examples above will be handled in the same way because it's executed in the same transaction. So for example in the first code sample with new statement inside the loop , postgres will create single planner for statement and even if we close statement and create new one in loop postgres will reuse cached one because it happens in the same session(transaction) and this cached planner will be deleted only when transaction will be committed(`connection.commit()`). Am I right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prepared statement duration lasts for the duration of the database session which is different from the transaction (the session ends when the client disconnects whereas the transaction ends -usually- with COMMIT or ROLLBACK).

Whether a single plan or several plans are generated depends at least on the following (it's PREPARE STATEMENT that generates the plan):

> A prepared statement can be executed with either a *generic* plan or a *custom* plan. A generic plan is the same across all executions, while a custom plan  is generated for a specific execution using the parameter values given  in that call. Use of a generic plan avoids planning overhead, but in  some situations a custom plan will be much more efficient to execute  because the planner can make use of knowledge of the parameter values.  (Of course, if the prepared statement has no parameters, then this is  moot and a generic plan is always used.)
>
> By default (that is, when [`plan_cache_mode`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-PLAN-CACHE_MODE) is set to auto), the server  will automatically choose whether to use a generic or custom plan for  a prepared statement that has parameters. The current rule for this is  that the first five executions are done with custom plans and the  average estimated cost of those plans is calculated. Then a generic  plan is created and its estimated cost is compared to the average  custom-plan cost. Subsequent executions use the generic plan if its  cost is not so much higher than the average custom-plan cost as to  make repeated replanning seem preferable.

[quoting Postgres SQL [`PREPARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) command]

Comment: If the JDBC `PreparedStatement` object goes out-of-scope (and heads for garbage collection), does Postgres continue to retain the prepared statement with its plan(s) until the session/connection ends? If so, is there any way back to that prepared statement on the Postgres side? [perhaps my asking is too much of a tangent]